# Does a wave packet have finite size?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction

Does the “amplitude” of a particle's wave packet decrease to 0 at some finite distance?

Comment: Are you asking about a wave function at some fixed time? Since it is normalized, it must decay to $0$ at large distances. Are you asking about what happens to a wave packet as it propagates over a time period? Then the answer is less clear. Some spread out as they travel. But not all do.

Comment: What I wanted to know was if in all cases the amplitude of the wave packet never actually attained the value 0 at any finite distance as opposed to actually attaining 0 at some finite distance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think a general statement for a wavepacket cannot be made. There could be wavepackets like those representing a particle in a deep quantum well that go zero outside the barrier while in other cases you could find a wave packet never becoming zero in case of a free particle where the wave packets are basically waves of equal amplitude since the probability of finding the particle is uniform in whole space.

In essence the more the particle is localised the more its wave packet starts resembling a dirac delta and its amplitude starts becoming zero everywhere except at a point.

Comment: Good answer. Just want to point out that the wavefunction of a particle in a finite well decays exponentially far from the well, so it might be considered infinite in a sense, even though it vanishes at infinity.

Comment: Yes. I forgot to mention the asymptomatic case , thanks for completing it.

Comment: Regarding: "In essence the more the particle is localized the more its wave packet starts resembling a dirac delta and its amplitude starts becoming zero everywhere except at a point."  I assume that "starts becoming zero" means atuially attains zero at smaller and smaller distances from the wave packets.